# Como enviar um GIF no Whatsapp programaticamente no Android?

Tags: android, whatsapp

Como posso enviar um GIF localizado na memoria interna do **meu aplicativo** direto para o Whatsapp programaticamente?

Comment: O objetivo do questionamento do @WallaceMaxters é separar o joio do trigo. Sua versão original da pergunta não dava a entender que era relacionado a programação, parecia mais um pedido de ajuda para usar um aplicativo.

Comment: Eu sou um poço de doçura, gente :)

Comment: Realmente agora entendo tudo que vocês estão dizendo, quando o W. Maxters respondeu eu interpretei de outra forma.

Comment: Removido o voto de fechamento,.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Conforme esta resposta https://stackoverflow.com/a/39656904/1518921 pode fazer isto (mas é claro que vai depender da versão do Whatsapp)

```
private void shareGif(String resourceName){

    String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String fileName = "sharingGif.gif";

    File sharingGifFile = new File(baseDir, fileName);

    try {
        byte[] readData = new byte[1024*500];
        InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", getPackageName()));

        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(sharingGifFile);
        int i = fis.read(readData);

        while (i != -1) {
            fos.write(readData, 0, i);
            i = fis.read(readData);
        }

        fos.close();
    } catch (IOException io) {
    }

    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    shareIntent.setType("image/gif");
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(sharingGifFile);
    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share Emoji"));
}
```

> Não testei ainda.

Comment: obrigado por responder Guilherme, oque está linha faz InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(getResources().getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", getPackageName()));

Comment: eu vi esse código mais como sou novo nisso não entendo muitas coisas novas que vejo... lendo o código com minha ignorância eu pensei nisso que disse mais eu não entendi porque lá em cima tem `String baseDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    String fileName = "sharingGif.gif";` e logo abaixo tenta-se ler o resource

Comment: Entendo, vou "destrinchar" o código e explicar parte a parte, pode demorar um pouco pois ainda não consegui um celular emprestado par efetuar os testes.

Comment: é da memoria interna do celular mesmo, já que um gif é bem pesado

Comment: prefiro assim, você me explicando, Obrigado!

Comment: Olá Guilherme Nascimento to usando esse código ta funcionando certinho, valeu!